# VisualStudio Online and pack Nuget packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I'm creating a repository in `Visual Studio OnLine` when I have some class libraries. I want to create (pack) and push for each of them a `Nuget` package in my private repository.

In a project there is a dependency on `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights`. If I create on my computer a package, it is working fine. If I try to do the same on Visual Studio Online I have an error:

> The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and
>   error(NuGet.CommandLine.CommandLineException: Unable to find
>   'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.2.6.4.nupkg'. Make sure the project has
>   been built.

This is the full error:

> NuGet Version: 4.1.0.2450 Attempting to build package from
>   'Vu.Common.Logging.AppInsightsEvent.csproj'. MSBuild auto-detection:
>   using msbuild version '15.6.85.37198' from 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin'. Use
>   option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of
>   MSBuild. Packing files from
>   'D:\a\1\s\Vu.Common\Vu.Common.Logging.AppInsightsEvent\bin\Release'.
>   Using 'Vu.Common.Logging.AppInsightsEvent.nuspec' for metadata. Add
>   file
>   'D:\a\1\s\Vu.Common\Vu.Common.Logging.AppInsightsEvent\bin\Release\Vu.Common.Logging.AppInsightsEvent.dll'
>   to package as 'lib\net462\Vu.Common.Logging.AppInsightsEvent.dll'
>   Found packages.config. Using packages listed as dependencies
>   NuGet.CommandLine.CommandLineException: Unable to find
>   'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.2.6.4.nupkg'. Make sure the project has
>   been built.    at
>   NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.AddDependencies(Dictionary`2
>   packagesAndDependencies)    at
>   NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.ProcessDependencies(PackageBuilder
>   builder)    at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.CreateBuilder(String
>   basePath, NuGetVersion version, String suffix, Boolean buildIfNeeded,
>   PackageBuilder builder)    at
>   NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildFromProjectFile(String path)
>   at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.ExecuteCommand()    at
>   NuGet.CommandLine.Command.ExecuteCommandAsync()    at
>   NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()    at
>   NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[]
>   args)

My configuration is easy. I added two `Nuget`, the first it is packing my nuget and the second push in the repository it.

I tried different configuration and also created manually the `nuspec` file but without result.

Any ideas? What is the right way to pack and deploy nugget packages?

[image: Visual Studio OnLine]

### Update

During the build the error I saw is like that:

[image: Error on VSTS Build]

Then I tried to create the same package on my local folder. I've only removed `OutputDirectory`, `NonInteractive` and the initial path. I can create the package without problem.

[image: Local]

Comment: Is the package restored before you run the pack command?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, seems your nuget packages failed to download the referenced nuget packages from url.

Instead of using customize nuget command, you could try to use **[Package: NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=vsts)** extension directly and select [Pack NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=vsts#pack-nuget-packages) and try agian.

[image]

Also [enable  Verbose Debug Mode](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/) to get more detail log by add `system.debug=true` for troubleshooting and narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I did that and the result is my question. :D

Comment: @Enrico The error is very clear, you are missing the reference of "Serilog.2.7.1.nupkg", you could try to remote to the build agent. And type  `%appdata%`   in run command and select nuget --nuget.config manually add the reference in the config file. Then try to build again. It should work as expectantly.