# TFS Automatic Build : Nuget Pack fail with code(1)

Tags: tfs, nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package

I'm trying to implement automatic builds in TFS for a WPF project. 
The automatic build works great, but I can't prepare a nuget package with the project.

Here is my build process in TFS :

[image: Capture of build process after fail]

If I remove NuGet pack and NuGet push, it works without trouble.

Here is the messages I get by TFS:

```
Found packages.config. Using packages listed as dependencies
NuGet.CommandLine.CommandLineException: Unable to find 'Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.3.3.0.nupkg'. Make sure the project has been built.
   at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.AddDependencies(Dictionary`2 packagesAndDependencies)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.ProcessDependencies(PackageBuilder builder)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.CreateBuilder(String basePath, NuGetVersion version, String suffix, Boolean buildIfNeeded, PackageBuilder builder)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildFromProjectFile(String path)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.ExecuteCommand()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.ExecuteCommandAsync()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)
Unable to find 'Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.3.3.0.nupkg'. Make sure the project has been built.
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Unable to find 'Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.3.3.0.nupkg'. Make sure the project has been built.)
```

In the logs, it says it doesn't find 'Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.3.3.0.nupkg'. I do use NuGet Restore before my build, and the build is correct. In the logs of TFS, I can see it uses 'Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.3.3.0'

I already tried to add `-Prop Platform=AnyCPU` on the commands used by NuGet for packing but it didn't change anything. I ran the command on my computer and it worked.

Here are the pages I already checked in my search of a fix :

- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/245349/the-nuget-command-failed-with-exit-code1-and-error.html
- [NuGet pack for TFS Continuous Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681547/nuget-pack-for-tfs-continuous-integration)
- [NuGet pack fails with "Unable to find '@(_OutputPathItem->'%(FullPath)..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583070/nuget-pack-fails-with-unable-to-find-outputpathitem-fullpath)
- [VisualStudio Online and pack Nuget packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715419/visualstudio-online-and-pack-nuget-packages)
- http://timjames.me/blog/2015/07/29/nuget-pack-fails-with-exited-with-code-1/
- https://www.benday.com/2017/05/03/walkthrough-publish-to-private-nuget-server-from-tfs2017-build/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may lack the configuration when you do the pack and select `.csproj` file.

If you have selected the `$(BuildConfiguration)` as your **Configuration to package** option.

You have to also specify the value of BuildConfiguration

[image]

Take a look at the difference of using `**\*.csproj` and `**\*.nuspec`

> Specify .csproj files (for example, `**\*.csproj`) for simple
>   projects. In this case:
>
> - The packager compiles the .csproj files for packaging.
> - You must specify Configuration to Package (see below).
> - You do not have to check in a .nuspec file. If you do check one in,    the packager honors its settings and replaces tokens such as $id$ and 
>     $description$.
>
> Specify .nuspec files (for example, `**\*.nuspec`) for more complex
>   projects, such as multi-platform scenarios in which you need to
>   compile and package in separate steps. In this case:
>
> - The packager does not compile the .csproj files for packaging.
> - Each project is packaged only if it has a .nuspec file checked in.
> - The packager does not replace tokens in the .nuspec file (except the     element, see Use build number to version package,
>     below).    You must supply values for elements such as `<id/>` and
>     `<description/>`. The most common way to do this is to hardcode the
>     values in the `.nuspec` file.

Comment: Since the nuspec solution works for now, I won't be changing it. But for my next package, I'll be sure to try this method.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to fix this

The workaround I found was to add a .nuspec file to my project. I changed the NuGet pack task to use the nuspec instead of the csproj.

Everything worked fine after that (as far as I can see) except for the package icon which is not visible yet. But that's another story !

The reference for nuspec is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec

A default nuspec is found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package