# Why is my project not getting packed with Azure Devops Nuget Pack Task

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, azure-devops, .net-4.7.1

As you can see below, I am able to pack the .csproj file from the command line on my machine.

[image]

But when I try to do it in Azure Devops with this configuration:

[image]

My build fails to pack the project.

[image]

None of my searching has provided information about what in my project is dependent on System.ValueTuple.4.4.0.nupkg.

For completeness, here is the project in solution explorer of VS 2017.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried specify the one project file instead of wildcard in the path to csproj or nuspec, like `src\Libraries\xxx.Abrams.common\xxx.Abrams.common.csproj`?  I have create d a simple sample but not reproduce this issue, and you can also try to create a new project to test it.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51045543/tfs-automatic-build-nuget-pack-fail-with-code1) it seems like this particular part of my struggle is due to not having a value in my configuration variable.

Comment: I'm now having an issue with packing a project that has a reference to a different (read: third party) package. All other projects seem to get packed fine, but this one using a package says that the package can't be found. Isn't this supposed to be handled as a dependency?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems you have resolved this issue? If yes, could please share your solution as answer?  This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread and we could close this thread. And now your question is some one using a package says that the package can't be found? Yes, the third party package should be handled as a dependency, you may need download the pack package to check if it handled as a dependency, and check if this dependency package is restored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **NuGet Pack** task was having issues packing projects because I didn't explicitly set the value of the `$(BuildConfiguration)` variable on my pipeline.

The secondary issue with the task not bringing in dependencies correctly is a [known issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5979) with `nuget.exe` which was mitigated by using the **MSBuild** task with the `/t:Pack` option.

My pipeline task for building now looks like this:

[image: MSBuild -t:Pack]

Make sure to take note of the parameters given to MSBuild for targeting `Pack`.

For .Net Framework, also take note of the **Powershell** task adding package references to the **NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack** package, which adds Pack as a target for MSBuild. I added this powershell task to the build so that devs don't need to add the package explicitly to new projects in this solution.

Comment: Could you show the details of the top task where you are adding the reference to the Nuget Package in the pipeline?